# Как заменить ключ подписи Google в уже существующем приложении на ключ другого приложения

Tags: android, google-play-console

Прямо сейчас у меня есть два приложения, у которых есть разные ключи подписи приложений, я хотел бы заменить ключ в одном приложении, чтобы он был таким же, как во втором приложении. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если приложения вы подписываете сами - то никак.

Если приложения подписываются гуглом, то вы можете в консоли поменять ключ, которым подписывается приложение на вашей стороне, перед тем как эту подпись удаляет гугл и заменяет своей. Возможно, это нужно через тех.поддержку делать.

Comment: Приложение сначала подписываю я, потом его уже подписывает гугл. Во вкладке, с подписями есть пункт, где можно запросить смену подпись. Там предлагается сгенирерировать ее этой командой $ java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo --output=output.zip  --signing-keystore=uploadkey.keystore --signing-key-alias=upload-key-alias --encryptionkey=xxxx Но я не знаю что означают эти параметры и не уверен, что я смогу создать ту подпись, которая мне нужна

Comment: @Danil, по идее, это команда просто выдаст вам ключ подписи, который у вас и так уже есть, в двух экземплярах. По идее, если вы хотите использовать один ключ для 2 приложений, то команду вам выполнять не надо, а надо взять тот ключ, который вы выбрали и его гуглу дать для приложения, подпись которого вы хотите заменить

Comment: При нажатии кнопки "Запросить новый ключ" я выбираю пункт "Я хочу использовать один ключ для нескольких приложений или предустановленных версий", затем там предлагается воспользоватся командой и загрузить zip результата, но если команду не выполнять, то откуда взять zip с нужной мне подписью?

Comment: Попробуйте вот так создать `pem` файл от будущего нового ключа (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756#create), а потом через тех.поддержку запросить добавить новый ключ, т.к. старый утерян, там надо будет `pem` файл из предыдущего шага добавить: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=ru

Comment: При потере ключа тех поддержка меняет только ключ загрузки, а не подписи. А мне надо поменять именно ключ подписи, который сгенерировал сам гугл

Comment: Если не ключ загрузки надо менять, но ключ подписи, то это, скорее всего, просто невозможно. Ключ подписи участвует в идентификации приложения в ОС. Если его сменить - то юзера не смогут обновить приложение без ручного подтверждения удаления всех данных приложения. Скорее всего Гугл тут ничего сделать не может. Возможно, в тех. Поддержке вам это подтвердят. Однако ТП у Гугла ужасна и не факт, что вам удастся с ними хотя бы связаться

Comment: Я сгенерировал новый ключ подписи и добавил его в гугл консоль тестового приложения, ключ подписи поменялся, теперь я хочу поменять ключи подписи в двух приложениях, но при этом я не смогу больше обновлять ключи. При этом я знаю, что срок жизни ключа 20 лет, как тогда его надо будет обновлять?

Comment: @Danil, боюсь, я совсем запутался. Попробуйте в тех. поддержку обратиться - возможно, они смогут чем-то помочь.